# Set custom DNS servers using Unbound

Tags: dns

I just switched from systemd-resolved to `Unbound` as described [here](https://blobfolio.com/2017/05/fix-linux-dns-issues-caused-by-systemd-resolved/) to fix some DNS problems with systemd-resolved in Ubuntu 17.10.

How can I just set up a list of preferred dns servers with unbound? Something like `nameserver 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4`.

And how can I check which servers are actually used?

Answer (score 1):

Just add this into your unbound.conf

```
 # Dns over TLS
    forward-zone:
            name: "."
            forward-addr: 1.0.0.1@853
            forward-addr: 9.9.9.9@853
            forward-ssl-upstream: yes
            forward-addr: 1.0.0.1
            forward-addr: 9.9.9.9
```